# How to read Adjacency list into NetworkX to create a directed graph?

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx, sna

I have a .csv adjacency list with row 1 indicating source nodes, and row 2 – target nodes. I try to read the file with NetworkX, but I always get an undirected graph. How do I create a directed graph from such a file? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`create_using=nx.DiGraph` parameter](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.adjlist.read_adjlist.html) to create a directed graph:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    H = nx.read_adjlist(f, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

Comment: dead link to docs, I believe this was the intended target: http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.adjlist.read_adjlist.html